# Dojo dijit/form/Select don't display the Label

Tags: javascript, dijit.form, dojo

EDIT: Thanks for the answer. But i have found the problem, the response value server.id wasn't set. Now everything works fine :).

I have a problem with dijit/form/Select. I create a Select widget in my JavaScript code, by adding the options like `mySelect.options=[{label:"test", value:1}]` the widget shows me the label. But when i set the options in my dojo/request function it doesn't work! By clicking to the drop down menu i can see the labels but not in the current display field.

Here is my code

```
function populateValuesForDeleteServer() {
request.get("jsp/loadServer.jsp", {
    query : "command=loadAllServer",
    handleAs : "json"
}).then(function(response) {
    // Array für die Liste anlegen
    var parameter = new Array(response.length);
    // Fülle die Parameter
    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        var server = response[i];
        parameter[i] = {
            label : server.name,
            value : server.id
        };
    }
    selectDeleteServer.options = parameter;
}, function(error) {
    // TODO was mit dem log anfangen
    alert("Fehler beim initialisieren der Auswahlliste für deleteServer");
    console.log("An error occurred: " + error);
});
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `dojo/store` to `FilteringSelect` and add `options` to store as data.

```
var store = new Observable(new Memory({
    data: options
}))

widget.set('store',store)
```

**Your code should be**

```
function populateValuesForDeleteServer() {
request.get("jsp/loadServer.jsp", {
    query : "command=loadAllServer",
    handleAs : "json"
}).then(function(response) {
    // Array für die Liste anlegen
    var parameter = new Array(response.length);
    // Fülle die Parameter
    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        var server = response[i];
        parameter[i] = {
            label : server.name,
            value : server.id
        };
    }

    //dojo/store with an obsrevable
    var store = new Observable(new Memory({
        data: options
    }))

    selectDeleteServer.set('store',store);
}, function(error) {
    // TODO was mit dem log anfangen
    alert("Fehler beim initialisieren der Auswahlliste für deleteServer");
    console.log("An error occurred: " + error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the addOption() method.

```
dijit.form.select.addOption(/*array of options*/).
```

Your code should like this.

```
selectDeleteServer.addOption= parameter;
```